# How do you access a stage instance name from a SWF embedded w/ the Flex compiler?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I've embedded a MovieClip symbol with the `[Embed]` syntax into my AS3 project, which I'm compiling with the Flex 3 SDK. That MovieClip has instances of other clips within it that are placed on stage with instance names. I can't just access them by instance name like I would if I were compiling with the Flash IDE.

How can I reference them?

Comment: Is the SWF you're embedding out of AS3? If not, that's definitely the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to both give them instance names in the IDE and declare them in the class you've embedded them on.

So say that you have instances of *baz* and *frr* on your embedded class InfoPopup, you need to declare them like this:

```
package foo {

    import flash.display.Sprite;    

    [Embed(source='../../../../../../assets/Assets.swf', symbol='InfoPopup')]
    public class InfoPopup extends Sprite {

        public var baz:Sprite;
        public var baz:MovieClip;

        public function InfoPopup(){
                trace("constructor!");
        }

    }

}
```

When added like this they have to be public properties or else the compiler will complain.